# call a shell script(command line tool) inside another shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using a tool called Droidbox for experiment.
The tool has a shell script **droidbox.sh** which I can invoke through terminal.

**droidbox.sh takes one argument i.e path of the apk**

Usage: ./droidbox.sh APK

I want to call the **droidbox.sh** through a shell script.

I wrote a shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash
ARG1="/home/xxx/a.apk"
/home/xxx/DroidBox_4.1.1/droidbox.sh "$ARG1"
```

I am getting error which says

```
python: can't open file 'scripts/droidbox.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anybody point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `droidbox.sh` is expecting to be run from the `DroidBox_4.1.1` directory (which presumably is where you are running it from manually). It can't find the `scripts/droidbox.py` file it expects in your current directory when you run that script. That's a poorly written script (not yours, `droidbox.sh`).

Comment: if you run an "ls" in the same directory you're executing your script in, do you see the "scripts/droidbox.py" folder/file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you're running the script in a different folder than the folder that houses your "scripts/droidbox.py" file.  You can fix this in the following way(s):

1. Move the "scripts/" folder to the directory that you're running this script out of using "mv /path/to/scripts/ ."
2. Move your customer script to the folder that contains scripts/droidbox.py and run the script from there

Answer (score 2):

Your error message does not come from your script, but from the called one.

It sounds like the `droidbox.sh` script is not very smart and requires you to set the current working directory before you can call it.

I would typically use also some more variables, so you better see what belongs together:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
BASEDIR="/home/xxx" 
DROIDDIR="$BASEDIR/DrroidBox_4.1.1"
APKFILE="$BASEDIR/a.apk"
cd "$DROIDDIR"
"$DROIDDIR/droidbox.sh" "$APKFILE"
```

If you dont use `set -e` you better combine commands which need to succeed together:

```
cd "$DROIDDIR" && "$DROIDDIR/droidbox.sh" "$APKFILE"
```

Otherwise the `cd` might fail when the directory is missing and all following commands execute in the wrong directory.